# Cpanel Website not working on HTTP - How to solve?

Tags: http, https, cpanel, namecheap

I am hosting my websites on Cpanel with Namecheap. I had a SSL certificates installed on a website that recently expired. I don't want to renew it since the domain is just for testing (not using it). Since the SSL expired, now the website won't load on HTTPS and when i try to open it on HTTP it redirects to HTTPS and gives an error. i disabled auto redirecting to HTTPS on Namecheap and uninstalled the SSL and still keeps redirecting to HTTPS

I think i need a code to force HTTP access in my .htaccess or something but i'm missing something here. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two services listening/running on the same port on your server. One port is specifically bound for one service/app only. In case you need to run several NodeJS apps on one server and bind them on ports, then you will have to choose different ports for each of your instances.

There are a few possibilities why this happens:

1. They have a global force HTTPS redirection in place or forcing HSTS header. If so, you have to reach their support to disable it for you if possible.
2. You have a local force HTTPS redirection in place. Please check your .htaccess file.
3. Your application is configured to work explicitly with HTTPS:// URL. If so, you have to re-configure it back to use HTTP://
4. Last but not least, make sure to clear your browser's cache, as you might have cached the redirect response to HTTPS.

If they lack support, I would definitely suggest switching to the web hosting provider. There are quite a lot of managed providers that would help in such situations.